# Reflection.Emit: AssemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint does not set entry point

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, entry-point

I am writing a concatenative language in C#, and currently it is interpreted, but I want to take the next step: compiling. To start on this, I tried writing a simple "Hello, World!" program emitter using System.Reflection.Emit. The code works without any Emit exceptions, but when I run the generated "test.exe" file, it throws the exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'IL_Test, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

I have tried googling for the answer, but to no avail. Perhaps someone here can help me? (please) The code I wrote is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ILCompileTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string ASSEMBLY_NAME = "IL_Test";

            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                new AssemblyName(ASSEMBLY_NAME), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(
                ASSEMBLY_NAME);
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Program", 
                TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public);
            MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                "Main", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static,
                typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(string[]) });
            ILGenerator gen = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello, World!");
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }));
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("ReadKey", new Type[] { typeof(bool) }));

            assemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint(methodBuilder, PEFileKinds.ConsoleApplication);
            File.Delete("test.exe");
            assemblyBuilder.Save("test.exe");

            Process.Start("test.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

So, the question is: **how can I set the entry point to the Main method I define?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing call to typeBuilder.CreateType(),
DefineDynamicModule must have exe name passed as second parameter.
Full working sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ILCompileTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string ASSEMBLY_NAME = "IL_Test";

            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                new AssemblyName(ASSEMBLY_NAME), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(
                ASSEMBLY_NAME, "test.exe");
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Program", 
                TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public);
            MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                "Main", MethodAttributes.HideBySig|MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static,
                typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(string[]) });
            ILGenerator gen = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello, World!");
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }));
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
            gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("ReadKey", new Type[] { typeof(bool) }));
            typeBuilder.CreateType();
            assemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint(methodBuilder, PEFileKinds.ConsoleApplication);
            File.Delete("test.exe");
            assemblyBuilder.Save("test.exe");

            Process.Start("test.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it! I also found out that I needed to Opcodes.Pop the return value of Console.ReadKey, and have a Opcodes.Ret command, to get the entire thing to work.

Comment: Do you know why the ModuleBuilder wants the file name? Does it even have to be the same as the value I pass to AssemblyBuilder.Save()?

Comment: I believe this have to do with poor choice of overloads for DefineDynamicModule - according to MSDN, two overloads create transient, and two create persistable module. File name must be the same, otherwise application will also fail. Specifying file name in two places comes from possibility to create assembly out of multiple modules/files.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to remember that.